# Questions about using Git

Tags: git, github

I'm brand new to Git. Could somebody give me a rundown of the typical process of using Git **to work with an existing repository for my employer** (or confirm that my understanding is not way off base). (notes: Windows XP, GitHub, Cheetah Shell)

My current understanding is:

```
1)  # Create directory called "someprojectsrc"
2)  # Move into my new directory
3)  git clone me@github.com:someprojectsrc.git
4)  git branch foobranch
5)  git checkout foobranch
6)  # Using my text editor, add new files, edit existing files, etc
7)  git add my_file my_other_file
8)  git rm unneeded_file
9)  git commit -m "Made some changes to XYZ, etc"
10) git push
11) # Manager pulls my branch and merges it with master, then pushes master?
```

I assume this is the process is for working on repository as part of a team. Am I missing anything? Also, does a developer typically have `commit` permissions to a large corporate repository? Does it work such that the manager can commit to master and other users can commit to branches that they create, or do you typically have to submit a patch somehow, and they somehow merge your patch into master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 7, the comma (`,`) is not right. Only spaces should be used for parameters separation.

The way I use git is with `remote`s. Instead of doing a `checkout`, I add `remote` sources like this:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:someproject.git
```

and then perform `push` like this:

```
git push origin master # given that you're on the 'master' branch
```

The whole idea would be:

```
1) # Create someproject dir
2) # Change to someproject
3) git init
4) git remote add origin git@github.com:someproject.git
# ... changes ...
5) git commit -m 'My commit message'
6) git push origin master
```

Comment: @ncuesta - I'm really new to this, so I don't understand when you mean in your 2nd, and 3rd lines. Doesn't `checkout` just change the branch you're committing to / working in? I guess, could you explain what your steps in order would be (at least pertaining to that area)? Thanks for your answer, btw.

Comment: @ncuesta - use pull request? Does that mean I should work in a fork rather than a branch, or you're just saying to use pull requests with a branch?

Comment: @ncuesta - also, in your numbered list, that looks like what I did when I created my own repository. I'm going to be working on an existing repository for this company.

Comment: @orokusaki: Those steps are the ones *I* use, I didn't mean they were *the correct* steps :-). `git init` initializes the directory, and the `remote add` line adds a remote source named `origin` that will be used for pushing the changes.

Comment: @ncuesta - sorry, I'm just confused.

Comment: @orokusaki: Regarding pull requests, read the "A Quick Note on Collaborative Development Models" section on the link I submitted above.

Comment: @orokusaki: I missed the part about the existing repo. Sorry! Have you read this: http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html ?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you read this [Guide](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/index.html) for using Git on Windows

If you move one step further, reading this awesome [Git Branching Model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) will improve your team's effectivity.